# How do I fix a undefined index error in Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal

**Problem**

I am getting a "Undefined index: node in include()" notice in Drupal for the below line of code. I've tried the below solution but I am still receiving the error. Any ideas?

**Code**

```
$url = drupal_lookup_path('alias', 'node/' . $related['node']->nid);
```

**The solution I tried**

```
isset($related['node']->nid) ? $related['node']->nid : "";
```

**Question**

Does anyone know why this error continues to occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error suggests the `$related` array variable doesn't have a `node` index.

First, make sure you're retrieving the node object correctly.

Then, perhaps try it like this to avoid errors:

```
<?php

$url = '';

if (isset($related['node']) && is_object($related['node'])) {
  $nid = $related['node']->nid;
  $url = drupal_lookup_path('alias', "node/$nid");
}
```